# Orleans EventHub stream provider

Tags: azure-eventhub, orleans

I am using the EventHubStream provider in a project based on Orleans. 
After the system has been running a few minutes Orleans starts throwing  a QueueCacheMissException while trying to push an event to OnNext from a producer.

i have tried to increase the size of the cache but that helped only for a while.

Is this a normal behavior due to the size of the cache? 
In this situation should i unsubscribe and subscribe again? i have tried to resume stream but that didn't work, the stream was in faulted state... any ideas?

Comment: What version of Orleans are you running?

Comment: I am using version 1.2

Comment: Hmm, there are multiple reasons to this and I'm currently short on time to troubleshoot. I think popping by to https://gitter.im/dotnet/orleans might make unblock you quicker. Then you can come back and record the notes here. It's OK ask questions like this there. :)

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that the service is reading events from eventhub faster than grains are processing them.  EventHub can deliver events at a rate of ~1k/second per partition.
The latest version of the EventHub stream provider supports backpressure that should prevent this problem, but it has not been released.  You can however build your own nugets.